# Creating wrapper objects for PDF library

Tags: c#, inheritance, ironpdf

I am having an issue wrapping my head around how to properly wrap a PDF library I am using called `IronPDF`.

`IronPDF` has a `PdfDocument` object.

My thought was to create a `IronPdfDocument` object that looks like this:

```
public class IronPdfDocument : PdfDocument, IPdfDocument
{
    public IronPdfDocument(string filePath) : base(filePath) { }
    public IronPdfDocument(Stream stream) : base(stream) { }
    public IronPdfDocument(byte[] data) : base(data) { }

    public Stream GetSTream() => base.Stream;
}
```

`IronPDF` also has a Rendering object that is called `HtmlToPdf` and my thougth was to create an `IronPdfRenderer` that looks like this:

```
public class IronPdfRenderer : HtmlToPdf, IPdfRenderer
{
    public IronPdfRenderer() : base() { }

    public IPdfDocument RenderHtmlAsPdf(string html) 
        => (IronPdfDocument)base.RenderHtmlAsPdf(html);
}
```

Then utilizing the interface objects in code like so:

```
public IPdfDocument Execute()
{
    IPdfRenderer renderer = new IronPdfRenderer();
    return renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(myHtmlString);
}
```

However, I am getting an error in my `IronPdfRenderer` object when calling `RenderHtmlAsPdf` trying to convert `IronPDF`'s `PdfDocument` to my wrapped object of `IronPdfDocument`.

I understand that at face value a `PdfDocument` may not be able to be casted to my `IronPdfDocument`, but I would like to create a more generic structure in my code that would help future proof my business logic as different Pdf Libraries can come and go. I was wondering if anyone could provide any help/insight into what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the error for anyone interested:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'IronPdf.PdfDocument' to type 'MyNamespace.Merge.IronPdfDocument'.
```

Comment: `However, I am getting an error in my IronPdfRenderer object`, can you please post the error details?

Comment: not able to convert object to more specific object

Comment: @zaggler - I updated my question with the specific error I am getting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240143/invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-objects-of-type-base-to-type-subclass. 

Does this help understand why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't cast to IronPdfDocument directly because it's not implemented the same interface that [PdfDocument](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html) implements, as a workaround, you can create a new object and pass the resulted stream to the constructor to create a new object and return it as following

```
public IPdfDocument RenderHtmlAsPdf(string html)
{
var doc= base.RenderHtmlAsPdf(html);
return new IronPdfDocument(doc.Stream);
}
```

Comment: really smart use of the base class.   This is the problem we are solving:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240143/invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-objects-of-type-base-to-type-subclass

Comment: this is good. doc.Steam will make the document identical.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. This is essentially what i did to resolve my issue.

Comment: If we open a Stream, please Dispose() it.  `System.IO.Stream : IDisposable`